# Where can I find examples of jsTree 2.0 with jquery 1.9

Tags: jquery-plugins, jstree, jquery-1.9

I cannot find documentation anywhere for jsTree 2.0 (http://plugins.jquery.com/jstree/) which works with jquery 1.9.  Even the "Test" directory in the download is empty.  Does anyone know if there are any examples anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Same here. I would like to use jstree in my project. I have downloaded the recommended version  "jsTree 2.0.0-alpha" (as said here: https://github.com/vakata/jstree). But all examples I have tried are not working. After changing the source of jstree.js to older version "jsTree 1.0-rc3" everything works like a charm. 
I would like to see one working scenarion for jsTree 2.0.0-alpha, just to start.

Answer (score 0):

Download files from https://github.com/vakata/jstree and set files in `docs` forlder with `IIS` or `Wamp Server` and open `index.html` file in the browser.

Also you can use from http://www.ztree.me/v3/demo.php. It's a very good tree view control.